# How long does it take to Erase All Content and Settings on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, security, restore, iphone

Corporate policy at my job requires a lockscreen passcode on iDevices with corporate email on them, even personal. Yesterday, I set my password, then 5 minutes later had to use it. When I entered it, the phone says it was wrong. I entered it the magic number of wrong times, and so began the Great Purge of 2013 (data wiped from device). I stopped this from finishing (power + home button until it shut down).

I'm willing to let this process complete, as long as I'll still be at 6.1.2 when it finishes. Does anyone know how long the process takes with a 16GB iPhone 5 (A1428)? I've read the [Apple article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2110) about it, which tells me that it supports hardware encryption, and the process should only take minutes, but I let it go for about 2 hours, and nothing. I wonder if, by "minutes" Apple means like 600 minutes or something.

Does jailbreaking affect the amount of time the wipe takes? Any input would be helpful. I'm just really trying to avoid 6.1.4.

Comment: The process does usually only take a few minutes (up to 10?) at most.  I'm not sure what could be causing it to take so much longer than usual and my only suggestions (force recovery mode and a restore) would result in you being updated to 6.1.4. Maybe track down & download the 6.1.2 IPSW file for your phone and attempt to restore using it by option clicking (Mac) or shift clicking (Windows) "Restore" in iTunes and selecting the 6.1.2 IPSW file?  I don't have a means of testing this at the moment but that seems like it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that, but since Apple has stopped signing 6.1.2, that won't work. I think I may have found a solution. Will post results if it works.

Comment: I've got the same problem too. I had to update my iOS, so I asked a friend. He said that you might need to reset the phone. So I did, from the time 2:30 all the way to now, 9:25. But still, it didn't work. During the middle of this time, I also asked another friend. She said that something might be wrong, because she reseted it in about 10 minutes. So I went up to see what to do. It said something about a hard reset. I couldn't do it, though, because I didn't understand what the USB of a phone would be. So if anyone knows an easier way to update my iOS, even if when i go to general settings, a

Answer (score 1):

So I verified that deleting the hardware encryption key should not take very long at all. My problem was that the phone was jailbroken on 6.1.2 (not sure what the EXACT problem was). By following [this procedure](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/how-to-erase-all-content-and-settings-while-jailbroken-without-losing-your-jailbreak.395478/), I was able to delete all content and settings manually, with the file browsers [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) and [iTools](http://itools.hk/en_index.htm). Unfortunately, it didn't delete the errant configuration profile that locked me out of my phone, so I still had to update to 6.1.4.

I wish I had the time to investigate the issue further, but as this is my primary phone, I just needed it back operational.

Comment: Link is dead :-(. Should've outlined the procedure in my answer instead of just linking it.